# Prove this stronger inequality with $\frac{e^x}{x+1}-\frac{x-1}{\ln{x}}-\left(\frac{e-2}{2}\right)>0$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

Let $x>1$ show that
$$\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}-\dfrac{x-1}{\ln{x}}-\left(\dfrac{e-2}{2}\right)>0$$

It seem this inequality can use derivatives solve it,But it is ugly.can you  help？

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}-\dfrac{x-1}{\ln{x}}-\left(\dfrac{e-2}{2}\right)\right)=0$$
and $f(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x+1},g(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{\ln{x}}$,But $$f'(x)=\dfrac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}>0, g'(x)=\dfrac{\ln{x}-\dfrac{x-1}{x}}{\ln^2{x}}>0$$

Unfortunately I don't know any nice expression for this 1-th derivative which could help. I'll be grateful for all useful suggestions.

Comment: If you take the derivative and consider the critical points of the function for which $x >1$, that may help you.

Comment: To get the derivative's zeros seems to be a nightmare. There might be some trick to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x+1}-\frac{ex}{4},\,\,g(x)=\frac{ex}{4}-\frac{x-1}{\ln x}.$$ Then $$f'(x)=\frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{e}{4}=e\cdot\frac{4xe^{x-1}-(x+1)^2}{4(x+1)^2},$$ and since $e^{x-1}>x$ for all $x>1$, we obtain $$4xe^{x-1}-(x+1)^2>4x^2-(x+1)^2>0,$$ since $x>1$. This shows that $f$ is increasing. Moreover, $$g'(x)=\frac{x-1-x\ln x}{x\ln^2x}+\frac{e}{4}=\frac{x-1-x\ln x}{x\ln^2x}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{e-2}{4}.$$ We will show that $g$ is also increasing for $x>1$; to do this, it is enough to show that $$x-1-x\ln x+\frac{1}{2}x\ln^2x>0,$$ or, equivalently, $$\ln^2x-2\ln x+2-\frac{2}{x}>0,$$ for $x>1$.

Set $h(x)=\ln^2x-2\ln x+2-\frac{2}{x}$, and suppose that $h$ has a root $x_0$, for some $x_0>1$. Since $h(1)=0$, there exists a root of $h'(x)=0$ in $(1,\infty)$. But, $$h'(x)=2\frac{\ln x}{x}-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}=\frac{2}{x}\left(\ln x-1+\frac{1}{x}\right),$$ and the last function does not have roots greater than $1$, which is a contradiction. This shows that $h$ has a fixed sign on $(1,\infty)$, and since $h$ goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, we obtain that $h(x)>0$ for $x>1$.

So, we obtain that $g$ is increasing as well. Therefore, $$\frac{e^x}{x+1}-\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=f(x)+g(x)$$ is increasing as well, which shows the inequality.

Comment: $h'(x)$ has a mistake, the right one is $\frac{2}{x^2}\left(x\ln x-x+1\right)$, to show $h_1(x)=x\ln x-x+1> 0, h'_1(x)=\ln x >0 $ when $x>1$ then the result is OK.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

(I have to admit that the method in this answer is "ugly".)

Multiplying the both sides by $2(x+1)\ln x\gt 0$ gives
$$2e^x\ln x-2(x-1)(x+1)-(e-2)(x+1)\ln x\gt 0\tag1$$
Let $f(x)$ be the LHS of $(1)$. Then,
$$f'(x)=2\left(e^x\ln x+\frac{e^x}{x}\right)-4x-(e-2)\left(\ln x+\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$$
$$g(x):=xf'(x)=2xe^x\ln x+2e^x-4x^2-(e-2)(x\ln x+x+1)$$
$$g'(x)=2e^x\ln x+2xe^x\ln x+4e^x-8x-(e-2)(\ln x+2)$$
$$g''(x)=2e^x\ln x+\frac{2e^x}{x}+2e^x\ln x+2x\left(e^x\ln x+\frac{e^x}{x}\right)+4e^x-8-\frac{e-2}{x}$$
$$h(x):=xg''(x)=4xe^x\ln x+2e^x+2x^2e^x\ln x+6xe^x-8x-(e-2)$$
$$h'(x)=4e^x\ln x+8xe^x\ln x+12e^x+2x^2e^x\ln x+8xe^x-8$$
$$h''(x)=12e^x\ln x+\frac{4e^x}{x}+12xe^x\ln x+28e^x+2x^2e^x\ln x+10xe^x$$
Now it's easy to see that $h''(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 1$ because each term is positive for $x\gt 1$.

Since we have
$$h'(1)=20e-8\gt 0,\quad h(1)=7e-6\gt 0,\quad g'(1)=2e-4\gt 0,\quad g(1)=f(1)=0$$ we can see that each of $h'(x),h(x),g'(x),g(x),f(x)$ is increasing for $x\gt 1$, and that $h'(x)\gt 0,h(x)\gt 0,g''(x)\gt 0,g'(x)\gt 0,g(x)\gt 0,f'(x)\gt 0,f(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 1$.

Comment: @egreg: thanks:)